# Derivative of symmetric matrix (function of symmetric matrix) w.r.t. its unique elements

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have an optimization problem to estimate a symmetric covariance matrix of order $q$ , say $\Sigma$, which is only formulated in terms of its unique elements (on and above/below the diagonal) that is 
$vech(\Sigma)=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...\sigma_h)$, where $h=\frac{q(q+1)}{2}$.

In the process of optimization, the first and second derivative of the log-likelihood  are needed with some component such as

$\frac{\partial\,\,\text{log}|\Sigma|}{\partial\sigma_{ij}} = e_i \,\Sigma^{-1} e'_i \,\,(\text{if}\; i=j) $

$\frac{\partial\,\,\text{log}|\Sigma|}{\partial\sigma_{ij}} = e'_j \,\Sigma^{-1} e'_i \,\,(\text{if}\; i>j) $,

where $e_i$ is the $i$th column of $I_q$, here I omit the component $e'_i \,\Sigma^{-1} e_j $ from the second equation as long as I only interested in the unique elements of $\Sigma$.
Is that right??, similarly derivatives of other functions such as $trace$ will be handled the same.

Answer (score 0):

No; $\log|\Sigma|$ depends on $\sigma_{ij}$ through both entries, the $ij$ entry and the $ji$ entry, since both change when $\sigma_{ij}$ changes; thus, both terms have to be included in the derivate. You can readily check this for the case $q=2$, where you can calculate the derivative and the inverse explicitly.

Comment: Great thanks for your reply, and your answer is completely correct, this is exactly the rule written in many reference of "Matrix Calculus". However, I put an assumption to restrict the matrix $\Sigma$ to its unique elements (on and below the diagonal, element with $ij^{th}$ such that $i \geq j$, so I deal with the problem as if it is not symmetric containing $\frac{q(q+1)}{2}$ elements instead of $q^2$ elements. I am still looking forward hearing from you on this comment. Am I right??

Comment: @N.I.ElZayat: Sorry, I don't understand what that means. The standard way to treat a symmetric matrix is to treat each of the $\frac{q(q+1)}2$ elements that can be independently chosen as one variable. If you're doing something else than that, I don't see the difference. Perhaps you can write it out in more detail for the case $q=2$ and point out exactly where you see the difference between your approach and the standard approach?

Comment: I am doing optimization using iterative approaches to estimate $\Sigma$, so, I restrict this symmetric matrix to its unique elements to reduce number of iterations of the program as long as I can build the full matrix at the end of my convergent program by coping the upper diagonal elements from the lower diagonal estimated elements. I wish I clear my point.

Comment: @N.I.ElZayat: Unfortunately that doesn't make it any clearer to me. It still sounds like the standard approach that anyone would take to optimizing symmetric matrices. I'm afraid you're going to have to make the effort to go into details and point out exactly what you consider to be the "standard" approach and where you believe your approach differs from it.

Comment: I want to thank you a lot, based on a paper I found which also want to treat the symmetric matrix in terms of its unique elements, I follow the rules of the derivations of the matrix (or function of it) w.r.t. its element and I found that it is indeed takes $ij$ elements as well as $ji$ elements, so you are completely right. I will adjust all of my derivations of the likelihood first and second derivatives accordingly. Thanks again